# p value for monthly trend

Tags: p-value, trend, boxplot

I have a distribution of values for each of 12 months.
When I draw the boxplots (one boxplot for each month) the median gradually increases, but the boxes overlap.

Which test do I have to use in order to tell whether this seeming increase is significant or not?
Also, how would I quantify the increase? e.g. if between January and Feb the median increased by 1, but the box plots for these two months largely overlap, is that even meaningful?

Comment: You would likely get a better answer if you told us more about your data - for example, are these the same units observed each month, or a new set of units each month? Are you interested primarily in whether the median is different, or the mean, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use time series regression, and test whether the slope/trend has a significant coefficient after accounting for months. [This page](https://otexts.com/fpp2/useful-predictors.html) might be a good place for more details.